# Copy jagged n-dimensional primitive array to new type in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I feel I might be missing something really obvious. I need to copy a jagged n-dimensional array in java from one to another primitive (Number) type (e.g., from double[][][][] to int[][][][]). My code below works using Object[]s. How can I (or "Can I even") generate a new type of primitive array of n-dimensions? (By "jagged" I mean some arrays at the same level may have different dimensions as in the example data). Any help appreciated.

```
    public class ArrayToNewType {

    public static void main(String... args) {

    Object loNew = arrayAsNewType(
            new double[][][][]
            {
                array1,
                array2,
                array2Nulls,
                array3a
            },
            int.class);

    }

    public static Object arrayAsNewType(Object pArray,
                                        Class<?> pNewType) 
    {
      Object[] lNewArray 
           = new Object[java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(pArray)];
      deepCopy(pArray,
               lNewArray,
               pNewType);         
      return lNewArray;
    }

    private static void deepCopy(Object pOriginal,
                                 Object pCopy,
                                 Class<?> pNewType) {
    if (pOriginal == null || !pOriginal.getClass().isArray()) {
        return;
    }
    for (int liIndex = 0;
         liIndex < java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(pOriginal);
         liIndex++) {
        Object lElement = java.lang.reflect.Array.get(pOriginal,
                                                      liIndex);
        if (lElement.getClass().isArray()) {
            int liElementLength =    
                    java.lang.reflect.Array.getLength(lElement);
            java.lang.reflect.Array.set(
                    pCopy,
                    liIndex,
                    !lElement.getClass().getComponentType().isArray()
                    ? java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(
                                                         pNewType,
                                                         liElementLength)
                    : new Object[liElementLength]);
        }
        else {
            java.lang.reflect.Array.set(pCopy,
                                        liIndex,
                                        castToPrimitive(lElement,
                                                        pNewType));
        }
        deepCopy(lElement,
                 java.lang.reflect.Array.get(pCopy,
                                             liIndex),
                 pNewType);
    }
    }
    // Sample data
    static double[][][] array1 = 
        {
            {{3D, 4D, 5D, 2D, 13D}, {8D}, {28D}},
            {{8D}, {4228.2D, 4D, -.29D, 3D}, {228D}},
            {{48D}, {228D}},
            {{48D}, {28D}}
        };
    static double[][][] array2 = 
        {
            {{8}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 3}, {28}},
            {{8}, {4228, 4, 29, 3}, {228}},
            {{248}, {228}},
            {{0}, {-2899}, {9}}
        };
    static double[][][] array2Nulls = 
        {
            {{8}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 3}, {28}},
            {{8}, {4228, 4, 29, 3}, {228}},
            {},
            {{0}, {-2899}, {9}}
        };
    static double[][][] array3a = 
        {
            {{8D}, {554D, 5D, 2D, 3D}, {28D}},                
            {{48D}, {228D}},
            {{48D}, {328.65D}}
        };

    static <T extends Number> Object castToPrimitive(Object pElement,
                                                     Class<?> pNewType) 
    {
    if (pNewType.equals(byte.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).byteValue();
    }
    if (pNewType.equals(short.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).shortValue();
    }
    if (pNewType.equals(int.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).intValue();
    }
    if (pNewType.equals(long.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).longValue();
    }
    if (pNewType.equals(double.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).doubleValue();
    }
    if (pNewType.equals(float.class)) {
        return ((Number) pElement).floatValue();
    }

    return (pElement);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is not very readable with names like `lo`, `po`, `li` and `lil`... Anyway, your `castToPrimitive` returns an object, not a primitive. You can't have a unified method that casts to primitive. Primitives don't have inheritance or polymorphism.

Comment: That's one of the drawbacks of primitive types: you need one function per type, just like `Number.intValue()`, `Number.doubleValue()`. However, you want a dynmaic number of dimensions, so you should stick with the Number classes Integer, Double, etc. and use ArrayLists for a better code style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach using reflection, but working directly with the primitive types:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class NdArrayCaster {
    private final static Map<Class<?>, NumberClassWrapper> TYPES = new HashMap<Class<?>, NumberClassWrapper>() {
        {
            put(byte.class, new ByteClassWrapper());
            put(short.class, new ShortClassWrapper());
            put(int.class, new IntClassWrapper());
            put(long.class, new LongClassWrapper());
            put(float.class, new FloatClassWrapper());
            put(double.class, new DoubleClassWrapper());
        }
    };

    /**
     * Returns a "deep casted" copy of ndArray with the given base type.
     */
    public static Object cast(Object ndArray, Class<?> baseTypeClass) {
        checkThatPrimitiveArray(ndArray);
        int dimension = getDimension(ndArray);
        NumberClassWrapper wrapper = TYPES.get(baseTypeClass);
        return cast(ndArray, wrapper, dimension);
    }

    /**
     * Throws an IllegalArgumentException if ndArray is not a primitive type array.
     */
    private static void checkThatPrimitiveArray(Object ndArray) {
        if (!ndArray.getClass().getName().matches("\\[*[BSIJFD]")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ndArray is not a primitive array.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the array's dimension.
     */
    private static int getDimension(Object ndArray) {
        return ndArray.getClass().getName().length() - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Casts an old to an array of the given type and dimension.
     * <p>
     * This is called recursive for each dimension.
     */
    private static Object cast(Object old, NumberClassWrapper wrapper, int dimension) {
        if (dimension == 0) {
            return wrapper.cast((Number) old);
        }

        int size = Array.getLength(old);
        Object newArray = wrapper.createArray(dimension, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Object child = Array.get(old, i);
            Array.set(newArray, i, cast(child, wrapper, dimension - 1));
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    /**
     * Class providing information for a primitive type.
     */
    private static abstract class NumberClassWrapper<N extends Number> {
        private final Class<N> primitiveClass;
        private final String jvmName;

        NumberClassWrapper(Class<N> numberClass, String jvmName) {
            this.primitiveClass = numberClass;
            this.jvmName = jvmName;
        }

        /**
         * Casts a number to the type represented by this Wrapper.
         */
        abstract N cast(Number value);


        /**
         * Creates a primitive array with the given dimension and the given size at the lowest dimension.
         * <p>
         * Example: `IntClassWrapper.createArray(3,4)` returns the same as `new int[4][][]`.
         */
        final Object createArray(int dimension, int size) {
            return Array.newInstance(getBaseClassForArrayCreation(dimension), size);
        }

        Class getBaseClassForArrayCreation(int dimension) {
            if (dimension == 1) {
                return primitiveClass;
            } else {
                try {
                    return Class.forName(getArrayJVMName(dimension - 1));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new Error("Cannot happen.");
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the JVM name of the corresponding primitive array with the given dimension.
         */
        private String getArrayJVMName(int dimension) {
            return String.join("", Collections.nCopies(dimension, "[")) + jvmName;
        }
    }

    private final static class ByteClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Byte> {
        ByteClassWrapper() {
            super(byte.class, "B");
        }

        @Override
        public Byte cast(Number n) {
            return n.byteValue();
        }
    }


    private final static class ShortClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Short> {
        ShortClassWrapper() {
            super(short.class, "S");
        }

        @Override
        Short cast(Number n) {
            return n.shortValue();
        }
    }

    private final static class IntClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Integer> {
        IntClassWrapper() {
            super(int.class, "I");
        }

        @Override
        Integer cast(Number n) {
            return n.intValue();
        }
    }

    private final static class LongClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Long> {
        LongClassWrapper() {
            super(long.class, "J");
        }

        @Override
        Long cast(Number n) {
            return n.longValue();
        }
    }

    private final static class FloatClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Float> {
        FloatClassWrapper() {
            super(float.class, "F");
        }

        @Override
        Float cast(Number n) {
            return n.floatValue();
        }
    }

    private final static class DoubleClassWrapper extends NumberClassWrapper<Double> {
        DoubleClassWrapper() {
            super(double.class, "D");
        }

        @Override
        Double cast(Number n) {
            return n.doubleValue();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // Sample data
        double[][][] array1 = {
                {{3D, 4D, 5D, 2D, 13D}, {8D}, {28D}},
                {{8D}, {4228.2D, 4D, -.29D, 3D}, {228D}},
                {{48D}, {228D}},
                {{48D}, {28D}}
        };
        double[][][] array2 = {
                {{8}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 3}, {28}},
                {{8}, {4228, 4, 29, 3}, {228}},
                {{248}, {228}},
                {{0}, {-2899}, {9}}
        };
        double[][][] array2Nulls = {
                {{8}, {3, 4, 5, 2, 3}, {28}},
                {{8}, {4228, 4, 29, 3}, {228}},
                {},
                {{0}, {-2899}, {9}}
        };

        double[][][] array3a = {
                {{8D}, {554D, 5D, 2D, 3D}, {28D}},
                {{48D}, {228D}},
                {{48D}, {328.65D}}
        };

        double[][][][] ndArray = {array1, array2, array2Nulls, array3a};
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, byte.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, short.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, int.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, long.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, float.class).getClass());
        System.out.println(cast(ndArray, double.class).getClass());

        Object[] objectArray = new Object[]{new Object()};
        try {
            System.out.println(cast(objectArray, byte.class).getClass());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Object array not working: check.");
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(cast(new Object(), byte.class).getClass());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Object not working: check.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @mee. This works perfectly. And it was easy to add overflow protection in the cast function so it solves my problem and more.